# Adding an empty column after the final column of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
upc_cd  chr_typ         chr_vl        chr_vl_typ
282151  HW APPLIANCES   001           0
821516  HW APPLIANCES   001           0
102054  HW MEDICINE     NON-DEAL      0
770054  HW SPORTS       001           0
010312  HW DIAMETER     002           0
```

I need to add an empty column after the final column of this dataframe.
After writing this DF to CSV there should an additional comma which represents the empty column.

Comment: `df.loc[:, ''] = np.nan; df.to_csv(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
df['new_col'] = ''
```

Comment: Thanks, This works for me. Actually I needed a column without any header, df[''] = ''

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new empty column to the end with:

```
df['new_column'] = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set NaN for new column like that

**df['new_col'] = float("NaN")**